# Software Development Kit version is not the same as WebSphere Application Server

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I have installed IBM WebSphere Application Server ND V7, and I want to install fix pack 7 on this WAS ND V7. So, I have installed Update Installer and installed fix pack on WAS ND, installed fix pack successfully. Now, I want to install WebSphere Application Server feature pack for XML, so tried to install this feature pack using IBM Installation Manager v1.6.2, but it throwing the below error,

Installation Manager detected one or more packages that cannot be synchronized. Installation Manager cannot manage installation packages until they are synchronized.

You can import the packages again to synchronize Installation Manager with your imported packages.

You must configure repository connections and ensure that you can access the network or repository media to keep imported packages synchronized.
  Package data for these locations was not synchronized:
    C:\IBM\WAS_ND_7
      The Software Development Kit version is not the same as the IBM WebSphere Application Server - ND version. 
Use another tool, such as the Update Installer for WebSphere Software, to synchronize the versions.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you install the same fixpack level for SDK as is installed for WAS. I.e. if WAS is at 7.0.0.7, please install SDK fixpack 7. For IM to be in synch with WAS, WAS and SDK fixpack levels should match.